# How to display validation messages in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find a way to display messages like "This field is required." the same way django default email message for invalid email. Could you help me?

[This is the way I want to display required field messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl7qy.png)

My forms.py looks like:

```
class NewAccountForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=30, required=True)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewAccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].label = "First Name"
        self.fields['email'].label = "e-mail"
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = ' form-control'
```

And the view.py:

```
def request_account(request):

  if request.method == 'GET':
    form = NewAccountForm()
  else:
    form = NewAccountForm(request.POST) 

    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']

  return render(request, 'portal/request_account.html', {'form': form,})
```

And I'm looping over fields in template like this:

```
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{field}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{field.non_field_errors }}
            {{field.errors}}
        {% endfor %}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's not valid syntax in your view; the is_valid if statement is missing a body. Python will refuse to run this code at all, which means it's not the real code you are using.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks for replaying. I realized that I mispasted some parts of the code. Now I've uptated it. But the problem still persists. Do you have any idea of how could I show the popup notification for required fields?

Comment: You can loop your field errors in your view and print whatever you want when the specific error appears...